# Golang io.copy twice on the request body

Tags: io, go, multipart

I am building a blob storage system and i picked Go as the programming language.
I create a stream to do a multipart file upload from client to the blob server.

The stream works fine, but i want to make a sha1 hash from the request body. I need to io.Copy the body twice. The sha1 gets created but the multipart streams 0 bytes after that.

1. For creating the hash
2. For streaming the body as multipart

any idea how i can do this?

the client upload

```
func (c *Client) Upload(h *UploadHandle) (*PutResult, error) {
body, bodySize, err := h.Read()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

// Creating a sha1 hash from the bytes of body
dropRef, err := drop.Sha1FromReader(body)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

bodyReader, bodyWriter := io.Pipe()
writer := multipart.NewWriter(bodyWriter)

errChan := make(chan error, 1)
go func() {
    defer bodyWriter.Close()
    part, err := writer.CreateFormFile(dropRef, dropRef)
    if err != nil {
        errChan <- err
        return
    }
    if _, err := io.Copy(part, body); err != nil {
        errChan <- err
        return
    }
    if err = writer.Close(); err != nil {
        errChan <- err
    }
}()

req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", c.Server+"/drops/upload", bodyReader)
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", writer.FormDataContentType())
resp, err := c.Do(req)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
  .....
 }
```

the sha1 func

```
func Sha1FromReader(src io.Reader) (string, error) {
hash := sha1.New()
_, err := io.Copy(hash, src)
if err != nil {
    return "", err
}
return hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil)), nil
```

}

upload handle

```
func (h *UploadHandle) Read() (io.Reader, int64, error) {
var b bytes.Buffer

hw := &Hasher{&b, sha1.New()}
n, err := io.Copy(hw, h.Contents)

if err != nil {
    return nil, 0, err
}

return &b, n, nil
```

}

Comment: I made it to work thx to @OneofOne i post the final result later when i cleaned up the mess i made

Comment: You really don't need that much code and you surely don't need to store an entire contiguous copy of your blob in RAM.  I've done a similar thing with multi-GB blobs on RAM starved devices without issue.

Comment: @Dustin what would you do in this case?

Comment: What are you doing with the stuff you write into that buffer?  Do it without writing it into the buffer.  Consider [this playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/0OqUUl3uNE) -- which doesn't work on the playground because you can't create files, but in can handle arbitrarily long inputs correctly with minimal memory usage.  I did a similar thing for a CAS which also verified an out-of-band hash and then renamed the file after closing it successfully.

Comment: As an alternative you can use this library [https://github.com/hyperboloide/sprocess](https://github.com/hyperboloide/sprocess) to deal with file upload streams

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't do that directly but you can write a wrapper that does the hashing on io.Copy

```
// this works for either a reader or writer, 
//  but if you use both in the same time the hash will be wrong.
type Hasher struct {
    io.Writer
    io.Reader
    hash.Hash
    Size uint64
}

func (h *Hasher) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = h.Writer.Write(p)
    h.Hash.Write(p)
    h.Size += uint64(n)
    return
}

func (h *Hasher) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = h.Reader.Read(p)
    h.Hash.Write(p[:n]) //on error n is gonna be 0 so this is still safe.
    return
}

func (h *Hasher) Sum() string {
    return hex.EncodeToString(h.Hash.Sum(nil))
}

func (h *UploadHandle) Read() (io.Reader, string, int64, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer

    hashedReader := &Hasher{Reader: h.Contents, Hash: sha1.New()}
    n, err := io.Copy(&b, hashedReader)

    if err != nil {
        return nil, "", 0, err
    }

    return &b, hashedReader.Sum(), n, nil
}
```

// updated version based on @Dustin's comment since I complete forgot `io.TeeReader` existed.

```
func (h *UploadHandle) Read() (io.Reader, string, int64, error) {
    var b bytes.Buffer

    hash := sha1.New()
    n, err := io.Copy(&b, io.TeeReader(h.Contents, hash))

    if err != nil {
        return nil, "", 0, err
    }

    return &b, hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil)), n, nil
}
```

Comment: @fabrizioM hash writes are guaranteed to not return errors. City wide 6 hours blackouts are fun

Comment: any idea how to implement this? i added the uploadhandle read func

Comment: @AnthonyDeMeulemeester I updated the code and added an example. I'd like to point out that your code is open to DoS attacks since you keep the file in memory (in a bytes.Buffer) and someone can keep uploading big files.

Comment: @OneOfOne thx alot, how can i prevent the DoS? flushing the buffer after?

Comment: @AnthonyDeMeulemeester i didn't totally follow your code but I'd say the best way is to use io.copy on the hasher directly but you won't be able to get the hash until after you send the file  or save a temp file on disk and then io.copy it.

Comment: I posted a [playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/0OqUUl3uNE) with a much smaller and cheaper mechanism.  (half the code is a test io.Reader just to produce some output).  This code reinvents `io.TeeReader`, but with a much more specific, yet easier to get wrong API.

Comment: @Dustin somehow I completely missed the existence of `io.TeeReader`.

Answer (score 26):

I would suggest using an [`io.TeeReader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) if you want to push all reads from the blob through the sha1 concurrently.

```
bodyReader := io.TeeReader(body, hash)
```

Now as the bodyReader is consumed during upload, the hash is automatically updated.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

The most direct way is to use `io.MultiWriter`.

But if you need the hash to produce the multipart output, then you will have to copy to a `bytes.Buffer` and then write the buffer back to each writer.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert the stream into string and create it again as many times we need.
e.g.

```
readerStream := your stream from source

buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
buf.ReadFrom(readerStream)
rawBody := buf.String()

newReader1 := strings.NewReader(rawBody)
newReader2 := strings.NewReader(rawBody)
```

But it will be great if it can be avoided.

I am not sure it is the best approach. But it worked for me.

Comment: string can work if the maximum body size is small enough to not care about memory usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Request.GetBody`:

```
package main

import (
   "io"
   "net/http"
   "os"
   "strings"
)

func main() {
   read := strings.NewReader("north east south west")
   req, e := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://stackoverflow.com", read)
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   // one
   io.Copy(os.Stdout, req.Body)
   // two
   body, e := req.GetBody()
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   io.Copy(os.Stdout, body)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http#Request.GetBody