# Read multiple time a Reader

Tags: go

I have two http handlers that use the same http.ResponseWriter and *http.Request and read the request body like this:

```
func Method1 (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var postData database.User
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&postData); err != nil {
      //return error
    }
}

func Method2 (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    var postData database.User
    //this read gives (of course) EOF error
    if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&postData); err != nil {
      //return error
    }
}
```

Because of I need to keep these 2 methods separated, and both of them need to read the request Body, which is the best way (if it's possible) to Seek the request body (which is a ReadCloser, not a Seeker?).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25671305/golang-io-copy-twice-on-the-request-body, basically: use [io.TeeReader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader).

Comment: thanks, I've add a sample code as answer, hoping this is useful for other users

Answer (score 4):

Actually, thanks to miku, I've found out that the best solution is using a TeeReader, changing Method1 in this way

```
func Method1 (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    b := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0))
    reader := io.TeeReader(r.Body, b)

    var postData MyStruct
    if err := json.NewDecoder(reader).Decode(&postData); err != nil {
        //return an error
    }

    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(b)
}
```

Comment: Wonderful. I took the liberty to write a [sscce](http://sscce.org/): https://gist.github.com/miku/293f253b706c4de1b75c.

Comment: Please note you need to close the Reader. This is usually done automatically by http server but of course you swapped it with a no-op closer.