# Is there a way to use the same request.Body in multiple handlers without manually write a lot of code or I need to change the way I'm doing this?

Tags: go, architecture, handler, middleware, go-chi

This amazing article here: https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/how-to-properly-parse-a-json-request-body explains very well how to write a Golang handler.

I need to use two handlers, one after the other, only if the first one gives error.

Like this:

```golang
func main() {
    r := chi.NewRouter()

    r.Post("/api", MyHandlers)
}

func MyHandlers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    err := DoSomething(w, r)

    if err != nil {
        println("OMG! Error!")
        DoSomethingWithThisOneInstead(w, r)
    }

}

func DoSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) error {
    // here I need to read request's Body
    // and I can use io.TeeReader()
    // and I can use all the code in the amazing article example
    // but I don't want to, because it's a lot of code to maintain
    res, err := myLibrary.DoSomething(requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    render.JSON(w, r, res) // go-chi "render" pkg
    return nil
}

func DoSomethingWithThisOneInstead(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // here I need to read request's Body again!
    // and I can use all the code in the amazing article example
    // but I don't want to, because it's a lot of code to maintain
    anotherLibrary.DoSomethingElse.ServeHTTP(w, r)
}
```

1. Is there a different method instead of reading twice or more the same `request.Body`?
2. **Is there a way to avoid writing all that code in the article (which needs to be maintained) and using open source libraries that do it better and are revised by thousands of smarter eyes than mine?**
3. E.G.: Can I use a [`go-chi`](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) method?

Comment: Is there a requirement that DoSomething and DoSomethingWithThisOneInstead have the type `func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)`?  If not, then add a `body []byte` argument to the functions.

Comment: +1 to @MuffinTop. There is no need for `DoSomething` and `DoSomethingWithThisONeInstead` to implement `HandlerFunc` in this example. Also `DoSomething`'s declaration does not return an error but its call site implies that it should return an error.

Comment: @MuffinTop I updated question with more code. As you can see I need `w` and `r` in both handlers.

Comment: @kingkupps I updated question with more code. As you can see I need `w` and `r` in both handlers.

Comment: What about using a TeeReader?

Comment: Example of using a `TeeReader` for a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31884093/read-multiple-time-a-reader

Answer (score 5):

Slurp up the bytes and use as needed:

```
func MyHandlers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
       // handle error
    }
    r.Body.Close()

    r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))
    err := DoSomething(w, r)

    if err != nil {
        println("OMG! Error!")
        r.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))
        DoSomethingWithThisOneInstead(w, r)
    }

}
```